# How to fixed terminal error in Goland, i cannot using ny terminal in goland

Tags: terminal, runtime-error, goland

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpyG0.png)
I am getting this error problem  in my terminal goland, how to fix it?

I updated and setting environment path in my local computer, but it doesn't work
I have also checked the PowerShell permissions on the Goland app but the terminal is still throwing errors

Comment: Can you share a stacktrace from the IDE logs as shown on your screenshot?